# How to access and create lifecycle rules/lifecycle management policy for azure storage account through java code

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I want to create a *lifecycle rule* or *lifecycle management policy* for a specific azure storage account through **java code** (not through terraform or azure portal). Any appropriate code snippet or reference will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to manage the Azure Blob storage lifecycle, you could create it with these following methods.

> Azure portal, Azure PowerShell, Azure CLI, REST APIs

So you could call [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/managementpolicies/createorupdate) to create lifecycle with Java code. You need to get access token, then call the API. See the sample code, note to change the HTTP request:

```
public class PublicClient {

    /*tenant_id can be found from your azure portal. Login into azure portal and browse to active directory and choose the directory you want to use. Then click on Applications tab and at the bottom you should see "View EndPoints". In the endpoints, the tenant_id will show up like this in the endpoint url's: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id} */
    private final static String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationResult result = getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials();
        System.out.println("Access Token - " + result.getAccessToken());
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        /* replace {subscription_id} with your subscription id and {resourcegroupname} with the resource group name for which you want to list the VM's. */

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupname}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines?api-version=2014-06-01");
        request.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + result.getAccessToken());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationContext context = null;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
            /* Replace {client_id} with ApplicationID and {password} with password that were used to create Service Principal above. */
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential("{client_id}","{password}");
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", credential, null);
            result = future.get();
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }
        if (result == null) {
            throw new ServiceUnavailableException("authentication result was null");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```