# Creating Azure Lifecycle Management rules from C#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to create Lifecycle Management rules for an Azure Storage Account directly from C#?

I know how to do it on the Azure Portal or with Terraform, and I have seen [the same question for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458371/how-to-access-and-create-lifecycle-rules-lifecycle-management-policy-for-azure-s), where the answer was to call the API directly. I will revert to this method if there is nothing else, but I'm interested if there is an "out-of-the-box" solution for this problem, most likely from some Azure package.

Comment: [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs)

Comment: @DTul - Wrong package. The package you referenced is for managing data inside Azure Blob Storage. The correct SDK is [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage#libraries-for-resource-management).

Comment: @GauravMantri thank you! I have been using the Azure.Storage.Blobs package but I have never found anything in it for lifecycle. Now I can see why, that answers my question.

Comment: Awesome! Would really appreciate if you can make use of this SDK to manage lifecycle management rules and post your code as an answer. It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @GauravMantri's answer, I have used  Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage package and created the management policy with the following code:

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }));

var storageClient = new StorageManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(token.Token))
{
    SubscriptionId = "InsertSubscriptionId"
};

// Defining the lifecycle management policy
var baseBlob = new ManagementPolicyBaseBlob(delete: new DateAfterModification() { DaysAfterModificationGreaterThan = 365 });
var action = new ManagementPolicyAction(baseBlob);
var filter = new ManagementPolicyFilter(new List<string> { "blockBlob" }, new List<string> { "test/" });
var definition = new ManagementPolicyDefinition(action, filter);
var rule = new ManagementPolicyRule(lifecycleManagementRuleName, definition);
var schema = new ManagementPolicySchema(new List<ManagementPolicyRule> { rule });

// Creating policy
await storageClient.ManagementPolicies.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync("InsertResourceGroup", options.StorageAccount.Name, schema);
```

The rule defined above deletes blobs in the `test` container after 365 days of the last modification.

Comment: what roles are needed to run this? I have Storage Blob Data Owner and I get forbidden, but maybe i messed up somewhere else. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let me update this answer with the new way of managing Azure resources, with the NuGet Azure.ResourceManager.Storage package. In this example I'll delete the blobs older than one month ONLY in the `test` container

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(includeInteractiveCredentials: true);
ArmClient armClient = new(credential);
SubscriptionResource? subscription = await armClient.GetSubscriptions().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.SubscriptionId == "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx");
    
var storageAccount = subscription.GetStorageAccounts(cancellationToken).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Name == "YourAccountStorageName");
    
var policy = storageAccount.GetStorageAccountManagementPolicy();
    
var data = new StorageAccountManagementPolicyData();
data.Rules = new List<ManagementPolicyRule>();
    
var dateAfter = new DateAfterModification();
dateAfter.DaysAfterCreationGreaterThan= 30;

var baseBlob = new ManagementPolicyBaseBlob();
baseBlob.Delete = dateAfter;
            
var action = new ManagementPolicyAction();
action.BaseBlob = baseBlob;
            
var filter = new ManagementPolicyFilter(new List<string> { "blockBlob" });
filter.PrefixMatch.Add("test/");
            
var definition = new ManagementPolicyDefinition(action);
definition.Filters = filter;
    
var rule = new ManagementPolicyRule(ruleName, ManagementPolicyRuleType.Lifecycle, definition);
rule.IsEnabled = true;
    
data.Rules.Add(rule);
 
policy.CreateOrUpdate(WaitUntil.Completed, data, cancellationToken);
```